# Compiling Java program in cmd with textures

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to start a game using cmd that has .png image in it. Everything works fine using IDE, but when I compile all source files and start a game in cmd it gives me error and only shows game window without any textures. If there's special way to compile this ? Becouse in IDE we add folder where all images are that program would know where to search it.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? How have you added the images? By making a folder and throwing the png in there?

Comment: To parapharse your question: some code that I won't show, that I execute using a command I won't show, throws an error that I won't show. What could be the problem? The problem is in what you don't show.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. Yeah I made folder and then I added it using "Open Module Settings" and masked that folder as "Resources".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the problem is the way you load textures. Try this:

-Make a package called "res" (without quotes) in your main source folder.

-Put your image in that package (through windows explorer or the mac equivalent)

And use this script:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.awt.Image;

public static Image loadTexture(String name) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(name);
    Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
    return logo;
}
```

Now you can load the image with `loadTexture("res/name-of-image.png")`.